# Android-Notification: make ticker text stay longer

Tags: android, notifications

I am working on JellyBean. The ticker text in notifications comes and goes away when the notification appears in the status bar.The notification icon stays there(in the status bar) until we clear the notification. Is it possible to keep the ticker text also in the status bar until the notification is cleared?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. That being said I've seen anything that specifically stated that it was impossible. I think you'd have to modify that at the system level rather than the application level though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry -- the ticker text, like a `Toast`, is designed to be transient. After all, there are other things that go in the status bar that the ticker text replaces.